# Javascript Form Validation Works in Chrome but not IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have written a client-side form validation script for a registration form that works great in Google Chrome but won't validate in Firefox or Internet Explorer??

Here is the entire script:

```
<!--- Registration Form Validation --->
<script type="text/javascript">

//Validate radio buttons
  function checkRadioArray(radioButtons){
    for (var k=0; k < radioButtons.length; k++) {
        if (radioButtons[k].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Initialize error messages
  function reportErrors(errors) {
      var msg = "There were some problems with your form submission. Please correct the errors listed below \n";
      var numError;
      for (var j=0; j<errors.length; j++) {
         numError = j +1;
         msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[j];
      }
       alert(msg);
  }

  //Validate text fields
  function checkLength(text, min, max){
    min = min || 1;
    max = max || 10000;

    if (text.length < min || text.length > max) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Validate select menus
function checkSelect(select){
    return (select.selectedIndex > 0);
}

//Validate Registration Form
  function validate(form){

    //Set Variables
    var errors = [];
    var roommate = form.Roommate.value;
    var room = form.Room.value;
    var SatSess = form.SatSess.value;
    var SunSess = form.SunSess.value;


    if ( !checkRadioArray(form.RegType) ) {
      errors[errors.length] = "Please select your registration type."
    }

    if ( !checkRadioArray(form.FirstTimer) ) {
       errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate if this is your first time attending this conference.";
    }

    if ( !checkRadioArray(form.Tshirt) ) {
       errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your Tshirt size.";
    }

     if ( !checkRadioArray(form.Room) ) {
       errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your room choice.";
     }

     if (room == "Double")  {

         if ( !checkLength(roommate) ) {
       errors.push("You selected a double room, please indicate a roommate.");
     }
    }

    if (SatSess != "off") {
       if( !checkSelect(form.Sess1_1) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 1.";
      }
    }

    if (SatSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess1_2) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your second choice for Session 1.";
    }
   }  

   if (SatSess != "off") {
       if( !checkSelect(form.Sess2_1) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 2.";
      }
    }

    if (SatSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess2_2) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your second choice for Session 2.";
    }
   }  

   if (SatSess != "off") {
       if( !checkSelect(form.Sess3_1) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 3.";
      }
    }

    if (SatSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess3_2) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your second choice for Session 3.";
    }
   }  

   if (SatSess != "off") {
       if( !checkSelect(form.Sess4_1) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 4.";
      }
    }

    if (SatSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess4_2) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your second choice for Session 4.";
    }
   }

  if (SunSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess5_1) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 5.";
    }
   } 

   if (SunSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess5_2) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your second choice for Session 5.";
    }
   }

   if (SunSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess6_1) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 6.";
    }
   }

   if (SunSess != "off") {
        if ( !checkSelect(form.Sess6_2) ) {
        errors[errors.length] = "Please indicate your first choice for Session 6.";
    }
   }


     if (errors.length > 0) {
       reportErrors(errors);
       return false;
     }
         return true;

  }


</script>

<!--- End Registration Form Validation --->
```

For some reason the if statements.....if (SatSess != "off") and  if (SunSess != "off") won't validate as true in Firefox or IE but they will in Chrome?? I had the same issue when when I try.... if (room == "Double").

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you given `name` attributes to form elements, or only `id`s?

Comment: What do FF/IE think the value of `SatSess` is?

Comment: Yes, all form elements have both names and IDs. When I dump the form values FF thinks SatSess = on. Which is why I don't understand why it won't validate when I try...if (SatSess != "off") or....if (SatSess == "on")....neither of those will validate in FF or IE??

Comment: Ok I think I found the answer.....if(document.getElementById('EnableSatSess').checked) ...where EnableSatSess is the ID for that radio button seems to be working across all browsers.

Comment: Please answer your own question. Otherwise it will stay on the list/tab 'Unanswered questions'.